# Java: read SSL certificate information from Trust Store programmatically

Tags: java, ssl

In Oracle JRE I can open ControlPanel -> Java -> Security -> Certificates and install custom SSL certificate.

Is there a way to list these custom certificates programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

See the API for java.security.KeyStore.